# Insert new row in data table VBA Excel2010 ActiveX

Tags: excel, activex, newrow, vba

I want to insert a row in my data table. When I try it manually (select row, insert new row) it works just fine, but when I try to add it into my macro, which is inside an ActiveX button(!) it says "Runtime error 438: Object does not suppoort this method". If I try the mecro in a usual macro, not inside the button, it works fine aswell.

How can I get rid of this problem?

```
Set wsd = Sheets("Data")
wsd.Select                      
With wsd
.Rows("5:5").Select
.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'Here appears the error
End With
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Select. Not for the sheet and not for the row.

```
Sub test()
Set wsd = Sheets("Data")
With wsd
    .Rows("5:5").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ nice :) BTW you also do not need "5:5". `.Rows(5)` will also do

Comment: Thank you! I immediatly had another error, but I forgot to reply while I solved it :)