# Copy a range of cells and insert multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I have several hundred junction boxes with unique ID numbers which all contain the same parts, I need to create a list which displays the list of parts under each ID number.

I have just started use VBA this morning and have cobbled together a macro from bits and pieces.

The macro does the following:
Prompts users to select the range of cells to be copied (variable cell_rng).
prompts users to select a  cell to start the process of inserting the copied cells (variable start_cell). 
Prompts users to enter the number of times the copy range should be entered Variable j) (total number of
   JBs). 
Prompts users to enter the number of rows contained in the range of cells to be copied (variable k).

The macro should insert the cell_rng between every row (junction box ID) of the original list.
It should start inserting the cell_rng below the start_cell and then insert the cell_rng k rows (k being the number of rows copied, and therefore the new position of the cell below the next junction box ID on the list) below the start_cell, then k rows x 1 below the start_cell, then k rows x 2 below the start_cell and so on until number j is reached.

However what the macro does is insert the cell_rng below the start_cell and then insert the cell_rng **k+1** rows** below the first cell_rng insertion.
So if k = 5 and start_cell = 1 the macro will insert cell_rng starting in cell 2, cells 7 to 11 will have no insertion and the process will start again on cell nine.
It then carries on to work as i want it to work inserting the cell_rng where it should.

Is anyone able to help me to get the macro to insert the cell_rng after every row on the original list?
Apologies if the explanation is hard to follow, writing down what you want a macro to do is not easy!

The code for the macro is below.

```
Sub Insert_Copied_Cells()
'
'Insert_Copied_Cells
'This Macro copies a range of cells and inserts x number of times below a             
 specified cell.
'The offset can be altered so that a copied range can be inserterd on 
 multiple lines without changed data already present.
'
'This marco misses the first 6 row for some reason, this needs to be 
corrected somehow..........

'
Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, k As Variant, l As Variant, cell_rng As 
Range, start_cell As Range
'i = number of repeated entries required
'j = number of repeated entries required
'k = number of rows in the range of cells to be copied
'l = number of repeated entries required
'cell_rng = range of cells to be copied
'start_cell = the cell below which the copied range should be inserted, this 
'is the reference cell for all the repetition of the range insertion

 Set cell_rng = Application.InputBox("Select Range to be Copied", "Obtain 
 Range", Type:=8)
 'promts user to select a range to be copied

 Set start_cell = Application.InputBox("Select the First Cell Below Which 
 Copied Range will be Entered", "Obtain Starting Cell", Type:=8)
 'promts user to select a cell to start the process

  j = InputBox("Input Number of Entry Repetitions Required")
 'prompts user to enter number of repeated entries required

  k = InputBox("Number of rows to be Copied")
 'prompts user to enter number of rows the selected range contains

  l = k + 1
 'adds one onto number of rows to be copied to allow for next entry

 For i = 0 To j
 'run through the code below from i= 0 increasing by 1 until number j is reached, then stop.

  cell_rng.Select
 'defines the range to select (range defined above at prompt)
  Selection.Copy
 'copies the range of cells
  start_cell.Offset((l * i), 0).Select
'selects starting cell to paste range into
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'inserts the selected range below the starting cell

 Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's all in where you're starting.
You should be inserting at A2, A8, A14, A20, A26, etc.
If each JBox contains the same info, why not just set k=5, and l=6 ?
start_cell should be 2. You're Offset starts at 0,0 (6x0), then 6,0 (6x1),
then 12,0 (6x2) etc. and that seems ok. I'm an amateur myself and I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to accomplish what you're doing, but I think it only needs to be done once to get things populated (just a guess). Hope this helps a little or gets you headed in the right direction.

Check this answer out for a similar issue by  @teylyn . Very simple coding for inserting rows. Nice and clean !!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639509/7793894